# Ignore accents in greek words when using elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I have a search input box that supports autosuggestion logic. The results are fetched from an elastic index whose analyzers (index_analyzer, search_analyzer) use as tokenizer: nGram, and as filter: standard, lowercase and asciifolding for the search_analyzer & lowercase and asciifolding for the index_analyzer respectively. 
What I am struggling to achieve but without any effect/result yet is to get result(s) even if the user has given a greek word without the accent (tonos). Otherwise, the user gets proper results and the mechanism works as expected.
I have to mention that the given string is matched against a specific field to the document set that includes greek words with accent. Moreover, this field is of datatype string and enabled to get analyzed.

The query is formed (using example string without accent that highlights the problem):

```
$searchString = mb_strtolower('Προταση', 'UTF-8')

$queryText = new Elastica_Query_Text();
$queryText->setField('name', $searchString)
$query = new Elastica_Query();
$query->setQuery($queryText);
```

A quick solution but not appropriate cause it's kinda heavy for this purpose, is to form a fuzzy query with min_similarity set to 0.7. Then it works thoroughly but the cost is significant.

All the work has been done using the elastica, let alone php. Could you please help to solve my problem ? It is imperative for me that a solution be found.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample document and a query term with an accent?